# Use of zip files as Themes in Resource files

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have this bulk load of html, js, css, less files including zip files (themes) to be placed in Resource file in Lotus Notes. Will it be able to view get the zip files? There are so many files in the themes folder and it's going beyond the allowable file path so I wanted it to be placed in zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a zip file in resources, then it will be served as a zip to browsers. So that's not the solution. You need to unzip it and add all files.

You can also put the unzipped files in the default HTML folder on the Domino server without adding them to database resources. On Linux, it's usually `/local/notesdata/domino/html/` and on Windows `C:\data\domino\html`.